# Could not parse mapping document from invalid mapping:hibernate

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, dbconnection

HI  i am getting this error ..tried a lott but have nt been able to find a solution. Can anyone please help me ....you can find the error from this link https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxEeexgXf53PQ1JqZWQ4SEloSjg/view?usp=sharing

hibernate.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class catalog="user" name="beans.UserDetail" table="USERS"/>
  <id column="ID" name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>
  <property column="UNAME" name="uname" type="string"/>
   <property column="PWORD" name="pword" type="string"/>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/dbtest </property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">pass</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
     <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name = "show_sql">true</property>
    <property name = "format_sql">true</property>
    <property name = "hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.testing.cache.CachingRegionFactory     
</property>
    <property name = "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <mapping resource="config/hibernate.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    <mapping class = "beans/insert"></mapping>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

userdetail.java

```
package beans;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class UserDetail {
   @Id private int id;
    String uname;
    String pword;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public String getPword() {
        return pword;
    }

    public void setPword(String pword) {
        this.pword = pword;
    }
}
```

insert.java

```
package beans;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


public class insert {
    public static void main(String[] args){




       SessionFactory sf = (SessionFactory) new Configuration().configure("config/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
       Session session = sf.openSession();
       session.beginTransaction();

       UserDetail user1 = new UserDetail();
       user1.setId(7);
       user1.setUname("testUser");
       user1.setPword("testPassword");

       session.save(user1);
       session.getTransaction().commit();


    }
}
```

Comment: carefully read the stacktrace... `the content of element type "class" is incomplete...`

Answer (score 1):

You closed the `<class>` tag. Try this

```
<class catalog="user" name="beans.UserDetail" table="USERS">
  <id column="ID" name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <generator class="assigned"/>
  </id>
  <property column="UNAME" name="uname" type="string"/>
  <property column="PWORD" name="pword" type="string"/>
</class>
```